# Neo4j set Label via neo4j driver query

Tags: neo4j

Hi how can I set Label in query;

```
exports.addNewLabel = function(req, res) {
session
.run("MATCH (n:User {id:{userId}}) SET n:{newLabel} RETURN n", {
  userId: req.params.userId,
  newLabel: req.body.newLabel
})
.then(function(result) {
  res.status(200).send({ succeed: true, data: result.records[0]._fields });
  session.close();
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.status(404).send({ succeed: false, data: err });
});
};
```

my post api query:

```
rest/user/addnewlabel/5a423325507c093948e9ef91
```

body :

```
{
   "newLabel":"Firm"
}
```

when I call my api for create new label I take this mistake as below code. when I set relationships as like also I get this error.

```
Neo4jError: Invalid input '{': expected whitespace or a label name (line 1, 
column 36 (offset: 35))
"MATCH (n:User {id:{userId}}) SET n:{newLabel} RETURN n"
```

Comment: In the current version of the cypher, you can not set a label using variables. You need or hard-coded a label value in the query, or use the APOC library.

Comment: I solve as like post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48059634/2958358 thanks

Comment: Added another way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062983/4989460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set labels dynamically via parameters, the same is true for relationship types as well.

You can use string concatenation instead :

```
session
.run("MATCH (n:User {id:{userId}}) SET n:`" + req.body.newLabel + "` RETURN n", {
  userId: req.params.userId
})
```

I would suggest to validate the request though.

Comment: I also found as like solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found new solution also I can write a query.

```
exports.addNewLabel = function(req, res) {
  var query ="MATCH (n:User {id:'"+req.params.userId+"'}) SET  n:"+req.body.newLabel+" RETURN n"
  session
   .run(query)
   .then(function(result) {
       res.status(200).send({ succeed: true, data: result });
       session.close();
   })
   .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(404).send({ succeed: false, data: err });
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a simpler, safer and more elegant way is to use the [`addLabels`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) procedure from the [`APOC library`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures):

```
session
  .run(
    `
     MATCH (n:User {id: {userId}})
     CALL apoc.create.addLabels(n, {newLabels}) YIELD node
     RETURN node AS n
    `, {
    userId: req.params.userId,
    newLabels: [req.body.newLabel]
  })
```